# How to use Retry Tempate (backOffPolicy) with AfterRollbackProcessor in Spring Kafka 2.2.9.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using a spring boot 2.1.9 with Kafka and MySQL and also implemented a chained transaction manager.

I want to set the backOffPolicy so that the retry can happen after a certain time. it's possible in the new spring Kafka version but due to some other dependencies, I could not able to upgrade spring boot.

As of now, I am using AfterRollbackProcessor to handle failed messages, now I want to implement backoffPolicy with AfterRollbackProcessor using **Spring Kafka 2.2.9.RELEASE**. Is there any way to implement it?

here is reciever config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaReceiverConfig {

    // Kafka Server Configuration
    @Value("${kafka.servers}")
    private String kafkaServers;

    // Group Identifier
    @Value("${kafka.groupId}")
    private String groupId;

    // Kafka Max Retry Attempts
    @Value("${kafka.retry.maxAttempts:5}")
    private Integer retryMaxAttempts;

    // Kafka Max Retry Interval
    @Value("${kafka.retry.interval:180000}")
    private Long retryInterval;

    // Kafka Concurrency
    @Value("${kafka.concurrency:10}")
    private Integer concurrency;

    // Kafka Concurrency
    @Value("${kafka.poll.timeout:300}")
    private Integer pollTimeout;

    // Kafka Consumer Offset
    @Value("${kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset:earliest}")
    private String offset = "earliest";

    @Value("${kafka.max.records:100}")
    private Integer maxPollRecords;

    @Value("${kafka.max.poll.interval.time:500000}")
    private Integer maxPollIntervalMs;

    @Value("${kafka.max.session.timeout:60000}")
    private Integer sessionTimoutMs;

    // Logger
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaReceiverConfig.class);

    /**
     * String Kafka Listener Container Factor
     * 
     * @return @see {@link KafkaListenerContainerFactory}
     */
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String> chainedTM, MessageProducer messageProducer) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        // factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTM);
        // factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        AfterRollbackProcessor<String, String> afterRollbackProcessor = new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>(
                (record, exception) -> {
                    log.warn("failed to process kafka message (retries are exausted). topic name:" + record.topic()
                            + " value:" + record.value());
                    messageProducer.saveFailedMessage(record, exception);
                }, retryMaxAttempts);

        factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(afterRollbackProcessor);
        log.debug("Kafka Receiver Config kafkaListenerContainerFactory created");
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * String Consumer Factory
     * 
     * @return @see {@link ConsumerFactory}
     */
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        log.debug("Kafka Receiver Config consumerFactory created");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    /**
     * Consumer Configurations
     * 
     * @return @see {@link Map}
     */
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollIntervalMs);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimoutMs);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offset);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        log.debug("Kafka Receiver Config consumerConfigs created");
        return props;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use listener retry but it MUST be stateful (you have that commented out). Otherwise, the retries will be performed within the transaction which is generally not what you want.

With stateful retry, the template throws the exception after it backs off; then the after rollback processor will perform a re-seek so the record is reprocessed.

As you say, in 2.3 we added a `BackOff` to the after rollback processor to make it easier to configure everything all in one place.

Comment: if I use stateful retry with afterRollbackProcessor, is it the transaction rollback will happen immediately or before the next retry?  because if the retry failed i will get the log trace and also 'transaction rolled back'  message before the every next retry  (not after every retry failes).

Comment: The back off policy is applied when the exception is caught; the exception is thrown to the container (and the transaction is rolled back) after the sleep determined by the back off policy.